# Smaller Tabs Monodroid

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

in my app, i have an ancticity with an tab host an tabs etc.
my problem is, that i want tabs with less height. you don't know what i mean? here:
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-17360783/Tabs.png.html

my tabs are 30dp high, at least that is what i have written into the height property, but as you can see, these tabs just won't shrink to that size. what do i have to do, that this blue region above the "real" tab will dissapear?

ps: witouht any elements as far down as the list with "0.25" and "Erhardt Schulze" the tabs would have the normal height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:clipChildren="false">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:isScrollContainer="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
                    <TableLayout
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbEqID"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqID"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqIDVar"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbEqDesc"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqDesc"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbEqDescVar"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right" />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskID"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskID"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskIDVar"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right" />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDesc"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDesc"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDescVar"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right" />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDate"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDate"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                            <TextView
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:id="@+id/lbTaskDateVar"
                                android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="right" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:clipChildren="false" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you attach or provide an example of your layout file?

Comment: nobody here who could help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your issue may be due to some xml nesting. I am not sure if the table that you have included should be above or below your tab host, but here is an example the table above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <TableLayout
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/UTlbEqID"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbEqID"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbEqIDVar"
                        android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/UTlbEqDesc"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbEqDesc"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbEqDescVar"
                        android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/UTlbTaskID"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskID"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskIDVar"
                        android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDesc"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskDesc"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskDescVar"
                        android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/UTlbTaskDate"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskDate"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/lbTaskDateVar"
                        android:hint="wie sieht dass denn aus?"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:clipChildren="false">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:clipChildren="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: at first, thanks for your help. now the business. i got this with your code, and height at 30dp [Tabs](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3110/xhlkp4ig_png.htm) the Tabs have the same height as normal. after setting the TabWidget below the FrameLayout, the Tabs will slide under the screen, showing no text anymore, when set to 30dp for example. the rest what you get with 30 dp is [this](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3110/856rdfxr_png.htm)